# Android find fragment by id log.d output

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have been playing around with fragments and I am a big fan of using Log.d to see the output of methods and such to better understand things.

I'm at the point where I'm using findFragmentById.

**When I use these Log.d statements:**

```
Log.d("APPTAG", "Fragment: "+ getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager));
Log.d("APPTAG", "Fragment is visible : "+ getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager).isVisible());
```

**I get these results:**

```
APPTAG﹕ Fragment: FragmentTwo{52742bec #1 id=0x7f070077 android:switcher:2131165303:1}
APPTAG﹕ Fragment is visible : true
```

So the way I understand this is that for a smooth user experience the current fragment as well as the previous and next fragments are created for a smooth transition between them.

I am using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) tutorial for setting it all up.
I have 3 fragments and only fragment one has a button that calls a method to use the log.d statements.

For those who don't want to look at the link. I'm using a ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter to create the fragments.

**Question:**

1. Can someone explain to me why am I not getting the values for
   fragment one?
2. If possible how can I get them?
3. Why when at first launch am I getting the values for fragment two (id info and is visible) when fragment one is currently in view/on screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why am I not getting the values for fragment one?

I'm assuming that by "fragment one" you mean the first page in the ViewPager.

Your statement:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager)
```

is returning the fragment for the pager itself, not the page fragments that are inside the ViewPager.  Notice the argument that you're passing in to findFragmentById - R.id.pager.  That's the id of the pager itself.

> If possible how can I get them?

It is possible to get access to the ViewPager's page fragments.  One solution is to maintain a collection of the current fragments inside your adapter by overriding instantiateItem() and destroyItem().  There is a full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager).

> Why when I am getting the values for fragment two does it say fragment two is visible when fragment one is currently in view/on screen?

I don't think "Fragment Two" is referring to any page inside the ViewPager - it's referring to the fragment that the ViewPager itself is in.